# How to detect a rotated radian?

Tags: c, angle, radians

I'm doing `LunarLander` in `C`. 
My ship rotates between `PI/2` and `-PI/2`. And rotation per step is `PI/ 20`. I need a way to detect when my ship rotated 1 radian. So, when 1 radian rotates, the fuel decreases me by 1 unit.

What I thought is to first pass my angle to degrees and then see if the angle is greater than 57, because 1 radian is 57 degrees.
But I couldn't write it in my program because the idea is incomplete.
While this is just something I thought, I think the solution comes from that side, compare with those 57 degree

```
while(1)
//code
    case SDLK_RIGHT:
        angle += SHIP_ROTATION_PER_STEP;
        if(angle > (PI/2)){
            angle = (PI/2);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case SDLK_LEFT:
        angle -= SHIP_ROTATION_PER_STEP;
        if(angle < -(PI/2)){
            angle = -(PI/2);
            break;
        }
        break;  
//code
//during the while
```

I need an idea to compare if all that moved my ship was 1 radian. If the sum of the rotations per step were greater than 1 radian. But I can't think how

Comment: Fuel is equally consumed by rotating in both directions. Count roation similar to angle, but upwards in both cases.

Comment: You know each `SHIP_ROTATION_PER_STEP` is `PI/20`. So each step is 9-degrees. So on each 7th rotation the ship will have rotated through 1-radian (either forward/backwards/or a combination of both).

Comment: You better calculate how much of the fuel is consumed by `SHIP_ROTATION_PER_STEP`.

Comment: Most likely, you should track the ship’s angle and the ship’s remaining fuel separately. When the ship turns a twentieth of a radian, increase or decrease the angle by a twentieth of a radian and decrease the remaining fuel by a twentieth of a unit of fuel. Also, do not be surprised when the sum of floating-point numbers differs from the sum you would get by using real numbers—there will be small rounding errors, and the fuel will not drop to zero exactly but may drop to something like −.00001 or +.00001 units of fuel, and the angle may have similar deviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an accumulator `total_angle`. Whenever the ship rotates in either direction, add the absolute value of the rotation. Assuming your rotations are in the floating-point `double` type that means this:

```
total_angle += fabs(angle); /* angle is the increment in angle */
```

Let's assume that `angle` and `total_angle` are simply measuring radians directly and not some scaled integer version or whatever. In that case, whenever `total_angle` reaches or exceeds `1.0`, we subtract a unit of fuel. At the same time, we subtract `1.0` from the accumulator:

```
if (total_angle >= 1.0) {
    fuel--;
    total_angle -= 1.0;
}
```

We're assuming that a single rotation is no greater than one radian, otherwise we'd have to make this a while loop.

Comment: I would have written something like `total_angle += fabs (old_angle - angle)`.

Comment: Perfect, i did it with the idea of both. @Kaz I tried it out of your way, but it didn't work out properly. I used the "old_angle" that Mathieu says. Thank you all for the comments

Comment: @ArturoAguilarLopez Right; `angle` in my pseudocode refers not to the current position but the update delta; that corresponds to `new_angle - old_angle`.

Comment: UV yet `total_angle` sounds mis-named given [@Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57190188/how-to-detect-a-rotated-radian#comment100890279_57190188).  Perhaps `total_rotations`?